# Material-table - if no data show message

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am using material-table https://material-table.com/#/docs/get-started. However I can't seem to find any information about showing a default message if no data is returned?

I am wondering if anyone knows how I would go about this. Below is the test table I have created (with fake data). Now if that data is empty I want a message to show where the table data would be saying "create your ad now", with a button.

```
import React from 'react';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';

export default function MaterialTableDemo() {

    const tableIcons = {
        Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
        DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
        FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
        LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
        NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
        PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
        Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
        SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
        ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
      };

    const columns = {columns: [
        { title: 'Ad Name', field: 'name' },
        { title: 'Status', field: 'status' },
        { title: 'Formate', field: 'formate'},
        { title: 'Cost Type', field: 'costtype'},
        { title: 'Ad Listens', field: 'adlistens',  type: "numeric" },
        { title: 'Ads Served', field: 'adserved',  type: "numeric" },
        { title: 'Budget', field: 'budget',  type: "numeric" },
        { title: 'End Date', field: 'enddate',  type: "date" },
       
      ]};
   
  const data = { data: [
    { name: 'Test Ad', status: 'Pending', formate: 'Radio/Podcast', costtype: 'PPL', adlistens:0, adserved:0, budget:'$100', enddate:'02-02-2025' },
    { name: 'ZTest Ad', status: 'Pending', formate: 'Radio/Podcast', costtype: 'PPL', adlistens:0, adserved:0, budget:'$100', enddate:'02-05-2025' },
    { name: 'DTest Ad', status: 'Pending', formate: 'Radio/Podcast', costtype: 'PPL', adlistens:0, adserved:0, budget:'$100', enddate:'02-01-2025' },
  
]};

  
  return (
    <div style={{ maxWidth: "90%", margin:'5vh auto' }}>
    <MaterialTable
      title="Your Ads"
      icons={tableIcons}
      columns={columns.columns}
      data={data.data}
      /*editable={{
        onRowAdd: (newData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState((prevState) => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.push(newData);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              if (oldData) {
                setState((prevState) => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowDelete: (oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState((prevState) => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
      }}*/
    />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: a minimal reproducible example on codesandbox will be better for other to catch up with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use material table's [component overriding](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/component-overriding) to achieve this. Here's an example of overriding the body to put a button in the table (I didn't add any CSS so it's ugly).

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-moore-h2fkg?file=/src/Table.jsx

Comment: But what about the if statement I take it I need one of those?

Comment: Do you mean you want the table to do something like `if data { show data } else { show button }`? If so, I'm sure there's a more elegant way of doing this, but this is the best I can come up with right now. 

Basically create a function that has the if statement. If data, display table with data. Else, display table with the button. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-leftpad-hmnye?file=/src/Table.jsx

Comment: thank you so very much. I don't understand why the developer of this plugin has not made it easier to do this.

Answer (score 8):

You could achieve this with a more elegant way, by using the `localization` prop like this:

```js
<MaterialTable
    localization={{
        body: {
            emptyDataSourceMessage: (
                <Button color="primary" className={classes.button}>
                    Create your ad now
                </Button>
            ),
        },
    }}
    {...otherProps}
/>;
```

Comment: As a note for those that came after -- if you pass 'undefined' into the data prop, then this applies.  if you pass anything esle (null, etc), you will get an error.

Comment: It is saying only `string` can be passed to `emptyDataSourceMessage`

Comment: @PrathameshMore do you mean Typescript is complaining?

Comment: Yeah, TypeScript is complaining @Bassem

Comment: The `material-table` library is quite abandoned and types are not always correct. You can just put `// @ts-ignore` comment on top and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Material table has built in functionality for this:

In options object you can add the `showEmptyDataSourceMessage: true` property that will enable a default message saying: "No records to display" if the data is missing and the table is empty.